# Convert string to date using arrow python

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime, arrow-python

I'm trying to convert string to date using `arrow` module.
During the conversion, I received this error:
`arrow.parser.ParserMatchError: Failed to match '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z' when parsing 'Wednesday 06 November 2019 03:05:42 PM CDT'`

The conversion is done using one simple line according to this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

`date = arrow.get(date, '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')`

I also try to do this with `datetime` and got another error:

`ValueError: time data 'Wednesday 06 November 2019 03:27:33 PM CDT' does not match format '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'`

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the `arrow` module and why are you referring to the Python 2 versions of the `strftime()` and `strptime()` functions?

Comment: @martineau a [module](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for dates. I edited the question using `datetime` also.

Comment: hardcoding timezone here like `datetime.datetime.strptime('Wednesday 06 November 2019 03:05:42 PM CDT', '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p CDT')` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with timezone, hard-coding timezone here works

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('Wednesday 06 November 2019 03:05:42 PM CDT', '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p CDT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you could just hardcode `'CDT'` into your code, as @Hamza Rashid auggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58739006/355230), that will break if the timezone information ever changes to something else, such as `'CST'` or perhaps `'-0600'`.

To avoid that potential issue, I'd instead use something like the following, which just ignores everything in the string from the last space character in it onwards:

```
import datetime

date = 'Wednesday 06 November 2019 03:05:42 PM CDT'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date[:date.rindex(' ')], '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(date)  # -> 2019-11-06 15:05:42
```